# Request to move my question to skeptics

Tags: discussion

There's already been a request made to move this question to skeptics since it currently appeared then, and still appears now that the question would get answers that attempt to answer the question; current of the three answers, mine is the only one that attempts to answer the question.

Why is it not possible to move the question to skeptics? Here's the question: [Does empirical research indicate that salary discussions between coworkers cause problems?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/does-empirical-research-indicate-that-salary-discussions-between-coworkers-cause)

Comment: Does it hold up to Skeptics' standards? I don't see any evidence that there is widespread belief one way or another, really. It just one side of an argument  people have in the workplace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We asked before as it was flagged for Skeptics, but a Skeptics mod didn't want the question at the time; I forget the exact reason, but I think the lack of a [*notable*](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) claim was the problem.

You'd need to find an unreferenced, notable claim like a major newspaper, political figure, scientist ect making a claim on this topic, not just "this question's answers said..."

To quote the canonical Meta post on Skeptics:

> References in questions are used to provide evidence that a claim is notable. We don't expect the sources to be scientifically valid, but to demonstrate either a lot of people have heard of the claim, or that some notable person(s) make it.

Comment: +1 @Rarity: Hey, thanks for commenting, I did not know that was the reason. So, I've now provided research that claims it's a bad idea via the answer I posted, but I get the sense that for the question to be on-topic on Skeptics that the question must have a claim by a well recognized source that does not provide reference to empirical research to back up their claim. Is my understanding correct? Thanks!

Comment: @blunders yep. Basically something that implies either an authoritative or popular source has indicated X is true, and you want real evidence indicating the veracity of that.

Comment: Thanks, currently not aware of notable source making such a claim, but now understand that what's needed, and why Skeptics declined the question. Thank you!

Comment: @blunders: As much as I hate to say this about the Daily Mail, this would count as a notable source: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1282398/Why-colleagues-salaries-secret.html